# SQL - compare data

Tags: sql

I have a table with data that looks like below. On this table a member can have multiple enrollments with different accumulator amounts. I want to find those members that have multiple enrollments with different accum amounts. What’s the easiest way to compare the data? Cursor, function??

| MemberId | EnrollId | Accum_Amt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1200 | 1200 | 23.12 |
| 1200 | 1200 | 23.12 |
| 1300 | 1300 | 45.16 |
| 1300 | 1301 | 32.14 |
| 1400 | 1400 | 12.56 |
| 1400 | 1401 | 42.18 |

The output should just be the members that fit the criteria.

```
MemberId
———————-
  1300
  1400
```

Comment: Could you have a member with the same enrollID with different accum_Amts?  Say member 1300 having only enrollID of 1300; but both 45.16 and 32.14?

Comment: Also, if you added a row of [1200, 1201, 23.12], different EnrollID with the same Accum_Amt, should the EnrollID of 1200 be returned?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest ways is to use a GROUP BY statement to group the data by MemberId and Accum_Amt, and then use the HAVING clause to filter the results based on the count of distinct enrollments for each member

```html
SELECT MemberId
FROM YourTableName
GROUP BY MemberId, Accum_Amt
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT EnrollId) > 1
```

Comment: Thanks..running this gives me the members where the accum amounts are the same

Answer (score 0):

*Extremely infrequently* a cursor; there's likely a better way.

[Fiddle:](https://dbfiddle.uk/JYwpcA_O)

- distinct isn't needed if enrollID is guaranteed unique per MemberID
- a simple compound having clause should do it.

.

```
SELECT memberID
FROM tblName
GROUP By MemberID
having count(distinct EnrollID) > 1 and Min(Accum_Amt) <> max(Accum_Amt)
```

Complete Example:

```
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT 1200 as memberID, 1200 as EnrollID, 23.12 as Accum_Amt UNION ALL
  SELECT 1200 as memberID, 1200 as EnrollID, 23.12 as Accum_Amt UNION ALL
  SELECT 1300 as memberID, 1300 as EnrollID, 45.16 as Accum_Amt UNION ALL
  SELECT 1300 as memberID, 1301 as EnrollID, 32.14 as Accum_Amt UNION ALL
  SELECT 1400 as memberID, 1400 as EnrollID, 12.56 as Accum_Amt UNION ALL
  SELECT 1400 as memberID, 1401 as EnrollID, 42.18 as Accum_Amt)
SELECT memberID
FROM CTE
GROUP By MemberID
having count(distinct EnrollID) > 1 and Min(Accum_Amt) <> max(Accum_Amt)
```

Giving us:

```
+----------+
| memberID |
+----------+
|     1300 |
|     1400 |
+----------+
```